# How do I conditionally render a component in Gatsby based on specific page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm building a website on Gatsby and I will like to be able to render a component conditionally based on which page I am. For example, in the footer I have a component that I don't want it to appear on the "ourcontent" page but yes for the rest of the site.

I tried doing this, which worked, however after running build gives me an error saying:
`"window" is not available during server side rendering.`

```
{ window.location.pathname !== '/ourcontent'
  ? <MyComponent />
  : null
}
```

Im working using a Functional Component.

How would I be able to achieve this? Any help will be extremely appreciated! Thank you very much in advanced!

Comment: Window is not available during build time. See https://css-tricks.com/how-to-the-get-current-page-url-in-gatsby/#understand-build-time-vs-runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `@reach/router`. Here is an ultra simple example.

```js
import { Location } from '@reach/router'


const IndexPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <h1>Hi people</h1>
    <Location>
      {({ location }) => {
        console.log(location)
        if (location === '/') return <p>You are on the homepage {location.pathname}</p>
        return <h1> you are not on the homepage </h1>
      }}
    </Location>
  </Layout>
)

export default IndexPage
```

This [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/v82ol26w9l) shows both the `@reach/router` and the `location.pathname` implmentations.

Comment: hi @apena, thank you so much for your response. I was able to solve using the `@reach/router` as you mentioned, however, when trying it like this using `location` I was still getting the error. But when using with `useMatch` it worked! I did this:

`const match = useMatch('/ourcontent/');
{ !match ? <MyComponent /> : null }
`
This way we are clear from any Build errors! :)

Answer (score 1):

On any Gatsby page component you should have a `location` prop. Then you can get the pathname using `props.location.pathname`. Pretty sure this should work on server-side-rendering (your build) as well.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and easiest (the cleanest) way to achieve it is to use the built-in `props` provided by Gatsby. As you can see in [their documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/location-data-from-props/), it exposes a `location` `prop` which contains all the information needed. Of course, because it's not a global browser object, such as `window` or `document`, it will be available during the server-side rendering as well as during the runtime.

You can simply:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"

const Component = ({ location, data }) => {
  return location.pathname !== 'ourcontent' ? <MyComponent /> : null
}
export default Component
```

You can improve it by removing the ternary condition with `location.pathname !== 'ourcontent' && <MyComponent />`, is not needed to return a `null`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response Ferran Buireu! I will try this